# WPF Create Storyboard Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, storyboard

I have a problem with running Storyboard for dynamically created UserControl in .net WPF.

These are examples of my classes:

```
class EventsPage {

    //  ...    

    public void AddEvent(Event @event) {
        var eventUC = new EventUserContrl(@event);
        eventUC.ExpandCollapseAnimation += ExpandCollapseAnimation;
        EventsStackPanel.Children.Add(eventUC);
    }

    private ExpandCollapseAnimation(EventUserControl eventUC, double height, double time) {

        //  Create frames using custom functions for creating them.
        var frames = new DoubleKeyFrameCollection() {
            StoryBoardsBuilder.CreateEasingDoubleKeyFrame(0.0, eventUC.ActualHeight),
            StoryBoardsBuilder.CreateEasingDoubleKeyFrame(time, destinationHeight)
        };

        //  Create Animation.
        var heightSizeAnimation= StoryBoardsBuilder.BuildDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames(
                FillBehavior.Stop, frames, eventUC.Name, new PropertyPath("Height"));

        //  Create StoryBoard.
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();

        //  Add Animations into StoryBoard.
        storyboard.Children.Add(heightSizeAnimation);

        //  Create final function.
        storyboard.Completed += (sender, e) => {
            eventUC.Height = destinationHeight;
        };

        //  Run animation.
        storyboard.Begin(this);
    }

    //  ...

}
```

And after launching it, at `storyboard.Begin(this)`, an exception is shown:
**`System.InvalidOperationException:`** `„Name „” cannot be found in the namespace „ProjectName.Pages.EventsPage ”.”`

I did something like this but for manually placed user controls in page, and it works, but this won't.

This is StoryBuilder code:

```
public static EasingDoubleKeyFrame CreateEasingDoubleKeyFrame(
    double frameTimeInSeconds,
    double value) {

    //  Create double key frame.
    return new EasingDoubleKeyFrame() {
        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(frameTimeInSeconds)),
        Value = value
    };
}

public static DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BuildDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames(
    FillBehavior fillBehavior,
    DoubleKeyFrameCollection keyFrames,
    string targetName,
    PropertyPath targetProperty) {

    //  Create animation.
    var animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

    //  Set animation end behavior.
    animation.FillBehavior = fillBehavior;

    //  Set animation frames.
    animation.KeyFrames = keyFrames;

    //  Set animation target object.
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, targetName);

    //  Set animation target property.
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, targetProperty);

    return animation;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the StoryBoardsBuilder, especially StoryBoardsBuilder.BuildDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames. It appears like you are trying to set the storyboard target to eventUC.Name. I guess it should be eventUC instead. Please show the builder so that we can actually see what you did wrong. Right now all the relevant details are hidden.

Comment: @BionicCode I updated post with code from StoryBuilder - this is tool code for quick storyboards implementation.

Comment: Thank you. How do you show the user control?

Comment: User Control is placed in StackPanel ```EventsStackPanel.Children.Add(eventUC);``` that is in ScrollViewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the target of the `Storyboard` wrong.

`Storyboard.SetTargetName` expects a **registered** element name.

You have two options: either use `Storyboard.SetTarget` or register the control's name and use `Storyboard.SetTargetName`.

### Solution 1: `Storyboard.SetTarget` (recommended)

The recommended approach is to use `Storyboard.SetTarget`, when creating the animation in C# (instead of the more convenient XAML). `Storyboard.SetTargetName` expects an element within a XAML namescope, having the `FrameworkElement.Name` set using the `X:Name` directive. Using `Storyboard.SetTarget` eliminates the requirement of the target element to be registered within a name scope.

**StoryBoardBuilder.cs**

```
class StoryBoardBuilder
{
  public static DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BuildDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames(
    FillBehavior fillBehavior,
    DoubleKeyFrameCollection keyFrames,
    DependencyObject target,
    PropertyPath targetProperty) 
  {
    //  Create animation.
    var animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

    //  Set animation end behavior.
    animation.FillBehavior = fillBehavior;

    //  Set animation frames.
    animation.KeyFrames = keyFrames;

    //  Set animation target object.
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, target);

    //  Set animation target property.
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, targetProperty);

    return animation;
  }
}
```

**Example**

```
class EventsPage 
{
    //  ...    

    public void AddEvent(Event @event) {
        var eventUC = new EventUserContrl(@event);
        eventUC.ExpandCollapseAnimation += ExpandCollapseAnimation;
    }

    private ExpandCollapseAnimation(EventUserControl eventUC, double height, double time) 
    {
        ...

        //  Create Animation.
        var heightSizeAnimation= StoryBoardBuilder.BuildDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames(
          FillBehavior.Stop, 
          frames, 
          eventUC, 
          new PropertyPath("Height"));

        ...
    }

    //  ...

}
```

### Solution 2: `Storyboard.SetTargetName`

`Storyboard.SetTargetName` expects a named `FrameworkElement` as animation target. The name of this element must be registered within the current XAML name scope. This is done automatically when naming elements in XAML using the `x:Name` directive.
Since you have decided to create the elements in C# you have to register the element name manually. In case there is no active name scope, you also have to create a new name scope manually.

The easiest to get access to an existing name scope is the reference of a named XAML element. On this element you call `FrameworkElement.RegisterName` to register an element. See [Microsoft Docs: Targeting Framework Elements, Framework Content Elements, and Freezables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview#targeting-framework-elements-framework-content-elements-and-freezables) to learn more.

**StoryBoardBuilder.cs**

```
class StoryBoardBuilder
{
  public static DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BuildDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames(
    FillBehavior fillBehavior,
    DoubleKeyFrameCollection keyFrames,
    string targetName,
    PropertyPath targetProperty) 
  {
    //  Create animation.
    var animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

    //  Set animation end behavior.
    animation.FillBehavior = fillBehavior;

    //  Set animation frames.
    animation.KeyFrames = keyFrames;

    //  Set animation target object.
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, targetName);

    //  Set animation target property.
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, targetProperty);

    return animation;
  }
}
```

**Example**

```
class EventsPage 
{
    //  ...    

    public void AddEvent(Event @event) 
    {
        var eventUC = new EventUserContrl(@event);

        // Name the element
        eventUC.Name = "MyEventUserContrl";

        // Register the element name in the current name scope manually
        // using an existing named element 
        EventsStackPanel.RegisterName(eventUC.Name, eventUC);

        EventsStackPanel.Children.Add(eventUC);

        eventUC.ExpandCollapseAnimation += ExpandCollapseAnimation;
    }

    private ExpandCollapseAnimation(EventUserControl eventUC, double height, double time) 
    {
        ...

        //  Create Animation.
        var heightSizeAnimation= StoryBoardBuilder.BuildDoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames(                    
          FillBehavior.Stop, 
          frames, 
          eventUC.Name, 
          new PropertyPath("Height"));

        ...
    }

    //  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for help 

Comment: You are welcome. I had a typo. Of course using `Storyboard.SetTarget` is the recommended solution. I accidentally copy&pasted `Storyboard.SetTargetName` which is definitely not recommended when using C# instead of XAML. `Storyboard.SetTarget` doesn't require a name scope registered element name.